# Adding and deleting objects between lists

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml, object

I have a trading card game (Like top trumps) Where there's a deck of cards on the left and one on the right, I want to pass objects between these lists of cards, which I CAN do. But not without using a switch case to select the new cards as in the code below, I need to pass the card objects and remove them so eventually one list will have all 30 cards and one
will have none, how do I do this when all my cards on the left are simply called nextCard? Can I use some sort of array? Please use some sort os code or pseudocode in your answers, as I'm just a beginner.

TL:DR; Need to move card objects between lists, Adding them to one list, deleting from another. Right now I'm using a switch statement to pass in object data to list. I'll answer any questions you ask.

```
List<Cards> myListofCards;
List<Cards> myListofCards2;

//First card will be displayed on the left on the screen
myListofCards = new List<Cards>();
nextCard = new Cards();
nextCard.cardName = "Character";
nextCard.strength = 45;
myListofCards.Add(nextCard);
listOfCards.ItemsSource = myListofCards;

//Second card will be displayed on the right on the screen
myListofCards2 = new List<Cards>();
nextCard2 = new Cards();
nextCard2.strength2 = "Character2";
nextCard2.age2 = 42;
myListofCards2.Add(nextCard);
listOfCards2.ItemsSource = myListofCards2;

//When the value of the card on the left of the screen is compared 
//to the one on the right, it is higher, so the card on the right
//should move to the deck on the left side. Just to test this out
//I used the following switch case statement. It works but, when I
//eventually have about 30 cards and they are being added and removed
//from the 2 different decks, the case statements obviously will not 
//work anymore, so what I want is to be able to move the different cards
//between lists without the switch case. 


int index = rand.Next(random.Count);
var i= random[index];
random.RemoveAt(index);

switch (i)
{
    case 1:
    myListofCards = new List<Cards>();
    nextCard = new Cards();
    nextCard.cardName = "Character";
    nextCard.strength = 45;
    myListofCards.Add(nextCard);
    listOfCards.ItemsSource = myListofCards;
    break;

    case 2:
    myListofCards = new List<Cards>();
    nextCard = new Cards();
    nextCard.cardName = "Char";
    nextCard.strength = 55;
    myListofCards.Add(nextCard);
    listOfCards.ItemsSource = myListofCards;
    break;
}

int index = rand.Next(random.Count);
var j= random[index];
random.RemoveAt(index);

switch (j)
{
    case 1:
    myListofCards2 = new List<Cards>();
    nextCard2 = new Cards();
    nextCard2.cardName = "Character2";
    nextCard2.strength = 45;
    myListofCards2.Add(nextCard);
        listOfCards2.ItemsSource = myListofCards;
    break;

    case 2:
    myListofCards2 = new List<Cards>();
    nextCard2 = new Cards();
    nextCard2.cardName = "Char2";
    nextCard2.strength = 60;
    myListofCards2.Add(nextCard);
    listOfCards2.ItemsSource = myListofCards;
    break;
}

public void cardSwapandScore()
    {
        winback.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        win.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (nextCard.power > nextCardComp.powerComp)
        {
            win.Text = "You win";

            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
            myListofCards.Add(nextCardComp);
            myListofCards2.Remove(nextCardComp);
            /////////////////////////////////////////////////
        }
        else
        win.Text = "You Lose";
        win.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        ////////////////////////////////
        myListofCards2.Add(nextCard);
        myListofCards.Remove(nextCard);


    }
```

Comment: Please provide a simpler and more complete code example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear here what `i` and `j` are, and you don't seem to be _removing_ any cards (which one would think would be part of a "move" operation).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, I've changed my code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you can't use the built in [List methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4(v=vs.110).aspx).

So given you have a card object in the first list and you want to swap it from one list to another.  You would simply add or insert it into the second list and remove it from the first list.

```
myListofCards2.Add(myListofCards[i]);
myListofCards.Remove(myListofCards[i]);
```

Or you could use a `RemoveAt(int index)`

```
myListofCards.RemoveAt(i);
```

Another option is to use a [queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) which resembles the structure of a deck of cards.

```
 var cardLeft = queueLeft.Dequeue(); // Removes next element and returns it
 var cardRight = queueRight.Dequeue();


if(cardLeft > cardRight)
  {
    queueLeft.Enqueue(cardLeft);
    queueLeft.Enqueue(cardRight );

  }
 else if(cardRight > cardLeft)
 {

    queueRight.Enqueue(cardLeft);
    queueRight.Enqueue(cardRight );
 }
 else
 {

   \\Do something for a tie

  }
```